# Change decimal format in WPF DataGrid at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, string-formatting

I use the WPF `DataGrid` to display data from an SQL Server View. I just provide an `ItemSource` to auto-generate columns and to show data.

For a numeric column, I need the user to be able to change the number of decimal places that are displayed.

After a deep search I've found the only solution is to set the `StringFormat` in an `AutoGeneratingColumn` event handler.

But I need to change the `StringFormat` at runtime. Could you help me with that?

Comment: You can try a converter.

Comment: I wonder if there's a simple solution for that. Converter seems kind of artifical.

Comment: You can implement InotifyPropertyChanged in the field of the POCO where the data is stored and change the values in the code behind or the viewmodel. Don´t forget to mark the binding in the xaml as TwoWay. In any case @Ayyappan is right and I think that this is better done in a ValueConverter

Comment: @SergeyKrivospitskiy Converters are very commonly used in WPF. Nothing "artificial" about them. One conventional solution here would be a multibinding with a multi value converter. You would bind both the numeric value, and a property specifying the number of decimal places. Both the numeric property and the decimal-place property would have to support INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Are these decimal places pre-defined shown in a dropdown, or they can be anything ?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to replace autogenerated bindings and add formatting on the fly without using converters. This code set format of column of currently selected cell

```
DataGrid dg; // Your DataGrid
var column = (DataGridTextColumn)dg.CurrentCell.Column; // Selected cell's column
var format = column.Binding.StringFormat;
var bind = new Binding(column.Header.ToString()); // Bind to the same column of underlying Source
bind.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
bind.StringFormat = "F2"; // Two decimal places, add your code here
column.Binding = bind;// Set new binding
```

Answer (score 0):

```
binding StringFormat={binding n3}
```